# Where to find data to explore the "Rescorla-Wagner model"?

Tags: data-request, social-process

The Rescorla-Wagner model ([wiki link description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescorla%E2%80%93Wagner_model)): " ("R-W") is a model of classical conditioning, in which learning is conceptualized in terms of associations between conditioned (CS) and unconditioned (US) stimuli." and is bases the dynamics of the changes in behavior according to a simple agent update which covers every agent in the group. There can be found implementations to produce the effect (simulate) [sim link](https://www.cal-r.org/index.php?id=R-Wsim) or analyze a dataset which is governed by this effect [code using tensorflow](https://github.com/pmandera/tensorflow-rescorla-wagner).

Where can datasets be found that have been used to investigate these dynamics? Or are there compatible datasets which are available for investigations similar to this?

The methodology requires a set of actor which have connectivity between themselves in a network sense, and a state value which is defined as a bounded number that is continuous or discrete.